# angularjs secure role based tabs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, security

I am developing an application in which i am using angularjs at client side and java,spring at server side,all communication is in the form of JSON.

The problem i am getting is about security.
I have multiple roles, user can have and based on these roles,tabs on UI are visible or not.

If i use JSP then it is easy to use taglib for this problem because jsp is compiled at server and returned html will not have html section for hidden tabs and there is no way by which end-user can see these tabs or their URL part.

But how to solve this problem in angular based application because whatever code i write in angular file,user can change it by firebug etc. and can see the tabs and their URLs.

example : i have following in my html :

```
<a href="users">Users</a>
```

I want to hide this thing completely if user is not having required role.

One solution can be writing some directive but user can edit the script of this directive and can see this thing in html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things :

- Implements an angular Service, giving your client side the authorization (obtained by REST)

Then, on the server side :

- you need to protect **ALL RESOURCES** (html, angular controllers, angular services, rest resources) depending on the user's rights. 
  May you can protect only Rest Resources if Client side's ones are not critical (I don't mind if my user get my html).
  This way, the user won't see the tabs he is not supposed to, but more important, he can't bypass your security in order to show it.

By protecting HTML, I mean that for the tab XX I use ng-include="'tabXX.html'", and I protect this html with Spring Security the same way I protect RestResources.

Comment: what do you mean by protecting html?Do you mean to have different html pages for different roles?

Comment: Answer edited, I use spring security to protect html admin specific pages.